# How to get a specific object in an JSON array in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a JSON column "jobs" that looks like this:

```
[
    {
      "id": "1",
      "done": "100",
      "target": "100",
      "startDate": "123123132",
      "lastAction": "123123132",
      "status": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "done": "10",
      "target": "20",
      "startDate": "2312321",
      "lastAction": "2312321",
      "status": "1"
    }
]
```

I want to filter the array by object key values. For example: To find all items that have `target > done`, `status != 0` and lastAction is yesterday to get response like this:

```
[
    {
      "id": "1",
      "done": "19",
      "target": "100",
      "startDate": "123123132",
      "lastAction": "123123132",
      "status": "0"
    }
]
```

I know I can extract the data to a `JSON_TABLE()` to do the filtering but I don't get the original object back(unless I recreate it back) and the solution is not dynamic.

Can this kind of array filtering can really be done in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT JSON_PRETTY(JSON_EXTRACT(jobs.jobs, CONCAT('$[', j.rownum-1, ']'))) AS object
FROM jobs
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
  jobs.jobs, '$[*]' COLUMNS(
    rownum for ordinality,
    done int path '$.done',
    target int path '$.target',
    status int path '$.status'
  )
) as j
WHERE j.target > j.done AND j.status != 0;
```

You also mentioned a condition on `lastAction`, but the example values you gave are not valid dates, so I'll leave that enhancement to you. The example above demonstrates the technique.

Comment: Thank you. I does work for filtering and reconstructing the object but not dynamic. This solution hard-codeds the keys, if another key is added(for example some extra job data) the query won't get it. The idea is to query the user table for his jobs, do a job and update the statuses while allowing extra data to be passed.

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. You only need to add the keys to JSON_TABLE() for fields you will have conditions on, plus the `rownum for ordinality`. If there are other keys, the JSON_EXTRACT() expression in the select-list will get the full object, including fields that you have not referenced in the JSON_TABLE().

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to do it using the JSON_EXTRACT and JSON_SEARCH functions.

Let's say your table is named `tbl_Jobs` and the `jobs` column is of type JSON.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Jobs
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(jobs, "$[*].target") = JSON_EXTRACT(jobs, "$[*].done")
AND JSON_EXTRACT(jobs, "$[*].status") != 0
AND JSON_SEARCH(jobs, 'one', DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), NULL, "$[*].lastAction") IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't solves it. I want the object that matches the conditions as the result, not the entire row that has the array in it.

Comment: SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_ARRAYAGG(jobs)) FROM ( Select * FROM tbl_Jobs ... the query in the answer) t

Comment: I don't actually get results with

 
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(jobs, "$[*].target") = JSON_EXTRACT(jobs, "$[*].done")